# Explicit form of the homeomorphism between $C[0,1]$ and $C[0,1]\setminus 0$

Tags: functional-analysis

How to construct the homeomorphism between $C[0,1]$ and $C[0,1]\setminus\{\theta\}$
in the explicit form?

Here, as usual, $C[0,1]$ is the Banach space of continuous functions $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ with the norm
$$
\|f\|=\max\limits_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|;
$$
and $\theta(x)\equiv 0$ $\forall x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: Interesting question, though maybe you should explain what motivated it. I wonder also whether $C[0,1]$ and $C[0,1] \setminus \{\theta\}$ could be isomorphic as posets.

Comment: Maybe this is obvious, but what is the underlying topology?

Comment: One way is to use the non-complete norm-technique as described by Bessaga-Pelczynski in *Selected topics in infinite-dimensional topology*, chapter III, §5: [page 1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Iyj8M.png) and [page 2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/G4o6M.png). You can make this as explicit as you wish.